# How to resolve the write access issue in git?

Tags: git, ssh

I am able to execute 'git push origin master' on all my projects. However, I created a new project and added it to my git repository using the steps outlined here. https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Now, I am not able to push to origin master for this new project.

This is the error that it keeps throwing at me -

```
Write access to repo/git/projectTisha denied for userA
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am able to push to all other projects under repo/git/ but not this one. 
any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I was doing wrong! Ha!

I had to create a new repository as well. Missed that step.